# Running a Query with to much Raw Data

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am trying to run a query to give me the result of past incidence over a period of time.  The raw data source for the query has too much data to return any of the newer information.  I have tried nesting the query in an array to divide out the way the query runs, and that didn't correct the problem.

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("Spread Sheet Key","Coaching Responses!A:Z"),"select Col1,Col14,Col4,Col3,Col7,Col6,Col8,Col15,Col10,Col11,Col13,Col17,Col18,Col19,Col20,Col21,Col22,Col26 where Col23 contains '"&Cover!E2&"' Order by Col1 desc",1)
```

I also tried this formula

```
=Query({Importrange("Spread Sheet Key","Coaching Responses!A:Z5000"),Importrange("Spread Sheet Key","Coaching Responses!A5001:Z")} "select Col1,Col14,Col4,Col3,Col7,Col6,Col8,Col15,Col10,Col11,Col13,Col17,Col18,Col19,Col20,Col21,Col22,Col26 where Col23 contains '"&Cover!E2&"')
```

The first code will not return anything past row 5000 the second code
 keeps giving me a parse error.

Answer (score 1):

correct formula syntax should be:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("ID1", "Coaching Responses!A1:Z5000"); 
        IMPORTRANGE("ID1", "Coaching Responses!A5001:Z")}, 
 "select Col1,Col14,Col4,Col3,Col7,Col6,Col8,Col15,Col10,Col11,Col13,Col17,Col18,Col19,Col20,Col21,Col22,Col26 
  where Col23 contains '"&Cover!E2&"'")
```

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?